# Casting an array of Objects into an array of my intended class

Tags: java, collections, casting, object

Just for review, can someone quickly explain what prevents this from working (on compile):

```
private HashSet data;

...

public DataObject[] getDataObjects( )
{
    return (DataObject[]) data.toArray();
}
```

...and what makes this the way that DOES work:

```
public DataObject[] getDataObjects( )
{
    return (DataObject[]) data.toArray( new DataObject[ Data.size() ] );
}
```

I'm not clear on the mechanism at work with casting (or whatever it is) that makes this so.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Because `toArray()` creates an array of Object, and you can't make `Object[]` into `DataObject[]` just by casting it.  `toArray(DataObject[])` creates an array of `DataObject`.

And yes, it is a shortcoming of the Collections class and the way Generics were shoehorned into Java.  You'd expect that `Collection<E>.toArray()` could return an array of E, but it doesn't.

Interesting thing about the `toArray(DataObject[])` call: you don't have to make the "a" array big enough, so you can call it with `toArray(new DataObject[0])` if you like.

Calling it like `toArray(new DateObject[0])` is actually better if you use `.length` later to get the array length. if the initial length was large and the same array object you passed was returned then you may face `NullPointerException`s later

I asked a question earlier about Java generics, and was pointed to this FAQ that was very helpful: http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html

Comment: Ok.  Is there any way to cast Object[] to DataObject[] then?  I don't understand what that function exists for, otherwise.

Sorry I'm trying to get these stupid questions out of the way now so they don't haunt me later.

Comment: I'm afraid there isn't.  You just have to use the other toArray call.

Comment: No, you can just create a new array and cast your objects one by one. In Java, arrays are hardly ever the way to go, though.

Comment: You can, sort of, "cast" Object[] to DataObject[] using System.arraycopy.

Answer (score 3):

To ensure type safety when casting an array like you intended (`DataObject[] dataArray = (DataObject[]) objectArray;`), the JVM would have to inspect every single object in the array, so it's not actually a simple operation like a type cast. I think that's why you have to pass the array instance, which the `toArray()` operation then fills.

Answer (score 3):

After Java 8 with introduction of streams and Lambda you can do the following too:

For casting a normal Array of objects

```
Stream.of(dataArray).toArray(DataObject[]::new);
```

For casting a List

```
dataList.stream().toArray(DataObject[]::new);
```