# Why does casting a Type[] to a Class[] throw a ClassCastException?

Tags: java, reflection, casting

Today i was writing some heavy reflection-using code, and i came across this behavior i can't explain: why does

```
Type[] types = ((ParameterizedType)m.getGenericReturnType()).getActualTypeArguments();
Class[] c = (Class[])types;
```

Throw a ClassCastException, when iterating over that same array and casting every single element, i.e.

```
for(Type t : types) {
    Class c = (Class)t;
}
```

succeeds?

I mean, if the casting of a single element to another class is possible, why isn't the casting between arrays of the same types possible as well?

There probably is a reason, but i can't seem to find one...

Comment: Perhaps this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/q/395030/61855

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't cast a `Type[]` to a `Class[]` because a `Type[]` is not a `Class[]`. It may sound trivial, but that's all there is to it.

If you could cast a `Type[]` to a `Class[]`, what would you expect to happen when one of its elements was a `Type` that isn't a `Class` (a `ParameterizedType` for example)?

Comment: i understand, but then shouldn't the ClassCastException be thrown only if one of the elements isn't a Class instead of being thrown everytime?

Comment: No, because the actual run-time type is not a `Class[]`, just as an instance of `Object` (created with `new Object()`) cannot magically be turned into a `String`. See my answer below

Answer (score 1):

Bear in mind that to cast to a `Class[]`, the object has to actually be a `Class[]`, not a `Type[]`. As an example, this will fail:

```
Object[] objArr = new Object[10];
Integer[] intArr = (Integer[])objArr;  // fail.
```

but this will work:

```
Object[] objArr = new Integer[10];
Integer[] intArr = (Integer[])objArr;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't cast whole array, because there is no guarantee that all the elements in the array are of type `Class`. What if one of them was some other implementation of `Type`?