# Java generic type with arrays

Tags: java, android, generics

I cannot correctly write the generic method for this:

```
private int [] loadIntArray(String key, int [] defaultArray) {
    int [] array = new int [4];
    for( int index=0; index<4 ; index++) {
        array[index] = sp.getInt(key + index, defaultArray[index]);
    }
    return array;
}
```

I wrote this:

```
private <T[]> loadArray(String key, <T[]> defaultArray) {
    <T[]> array = new <T[LEVELS]>;
    for( int index=0; index<4 ; index++) {
        array[index] = sp.getInt(key + index, defaultArray[index]);
    }
    return array;
}
```

But it does not compile.
I get several errors, "Return type for method is missing", "Type expected after private token".

What would be the right way to write it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll return an array of type `T`, not a certain type `T[]`.

This will be more in the direction you want to go.

```
private <T> T[] loadIntArray(String key, T[] defaultArray) {
    T[] array = new T[4]; // Need more info to correct this
    for (int index = 0; index < 4; index++) {
        array[index] = sp.getInt(key + index, defaultArray[index]);
    }
    return array;
}
```

Comment: Almost perfect! The `new T[4]` still does not compile "Cannot create a generic array of T"

Comment: Read this! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013683/creating-generic-arrays-in-java

Answer (score 3):

In order to achieve  that you must add a `class parameter` to your method

```
Class<T> type
```

your method look now as follow

```
 private <T> T[] loadArray(Class<T> type, String key, T[] defaultArray) {
      T[] array = (T[]) Array.newInstance(type, defaultArray.length);
      for (int index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
         array[index] = sp.getInt(key + index, defaultArray[index]);
      }
      return array;
   }
```

Update after the question:
**How would a call to this method look like? (for example for type "int")?**

When creating a Pair object, you cannot substitute a primitive type for the type parameter K or V:

`Pair<int, char> p = new Pair<>(8, 'a');`  // compile-time error
You can substitute only non-primitive types for the type parameters K and V:

```
Pair<Integer, Character> p = new Pair<>(8, 'a');
```

**A possible workaround** 
(The only way to pass it in a generic manner and keep it as a primitive array is as an Object.)

```
Object a[]= {1,2,3};
loadArray(Object.class, "test", a);
```

Or you can use a non primitiv type (Integer)

```
Integer a[]= {1,2,3};
loadArray(Integer.class, "test", a);
```

Comment: How would a call to this method look like? (for example for type "int"

Comment: The only way to pass it in a generic manner and keep it as a primitive array is as an Object.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `defaultArray` will always be `nil` and will always be an array of the component type `T`, you can use its type to construct the new array:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;

private <T> T[] loadIntArray(String key, T[] defaultArray) {
    T[] array = (T[])Array.newInstance(defaultArray.getClass().getComponentType(), 4);
    for (int index = 0; index < 4; index++) {
        array[index] = sp.getInt(key + index, defaultArray[index]);
    }
    return array;
}
```

Note that however, if the `defaultArray`'s runtime type is an array of some subtype of `T`, this won't work. It will cause an `ArrayStoreException`.

Answer (score 0):

To start with, the method signature should look like this:

```
private <T> T[] loadArray(String key, T[] defaultArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

This the OP.
Although this is not the marked answer I wanted to post the final code that compiles for the sake of those who want to see it.

*One important thing that was not mentioned in other answers is that Java generics do not support primitve types (int, float, ...) only objects. So I had to change my arrays to be of Integer and Float instead.*

```
private <T> void loadArray(final T[] array, final String key, final T[] defaultArray) {
    int count = array.length;
    for( int index = 0; index < count; index++ ) {
        //if( array[index] instanceof PointF ) {
        if( array instanceof PointF[] ) {
            PointF element = new PointF();
            element.x = sp.getFloat(key + index, (Float) defaultArray[index]);
            element.y = sp.getFloat(key + index, (Float) defaultArray[index]);
            array[index] = (T) element;
        //} else if( array[index] instanceof Float ) {
        } else if( array instanceof Float[] ) {
            Float element = sp.getFloat(key + index, (Float) defaultArray[index]);
            array[index] = (T) element;
        //} else if( array[index] instanceof Integer ) {
        } else if( array instanceof Integer[] ) {
            Integer element = sp.getInt(key + index, (Integer) defaultArray[index]);
            array[index] = (T) element;
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**
It turns out that if the array is dimensioned, but not initialized,

```
array[index] instanceof Integer
```

returns `false`, so I changed the test to

```
arrray instanceof Integer[]
```

which returns `true` even if the array elements are `null`.