# Resolving ClassCastException in this code

Tags: java

I have this method getData as shown .
It is expecting an array of bag Objects as shown 
please see the code below :

```
public static String getData(Bag[] bag)
 {

 }

public class Bag
{
 public char side;
}
```

But , when i tried i am getting ClassCastException .
**I have done this way :**

```
Object bagArray[] = new Object[1];
Bag  bagData = new Bag();
bagData.side = 'S';
bagArray[0]=bagData;
String bagData = ApplicationUtil.getData(Bag[]) bagArray);
```

Please let me , how to resolve this error ??

Comment: The code as you have posted it wont compile, as the line `String bagData = ApplicationUtil.getData(Bag[]) bagArray);` is missing an opening parenthesis.

Comment: Also: Please post the exception (with a reference for the line number in it) and the code for `ApplicationUtil.getData()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `bagArray` is an array of `Object` and not an array of `Bag`.

Either change that to `Bag bagArray[] = new Bag [1];` or use a `Collection` (e.g. `List`) instead - note that you can cast `List<Object>` to `List<Bag>` but *that is an unsafe operation and not recommended unless you know what you're doing*.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you creating an Object array rather than an array of Bag objects?

Try just changing the first line to `Bag[] bagArray = new Bag[1]`.

As an `Object` array can hold any kind of object, so I don't think it can be cast to a `Bag` array. You could however cast `bagArray[0]` to a `Bag` object.

In future, try using a List or other collection rather than an array for stuff like this.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to cast an Object[] into a Bag[]. Not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You bagArray is an Object array and not a Bag array. Just because it is capable of holding an object of type Bag (which is a subclass of Object), does not mean the vice versa. You are trying to cast Object to Bag type, which is not allowed. Define you bag array in the following way

```
Object bagArray[] = new Bag[];
```

Answer (score 0):

See this question: [Quick Java question: Casting an array of Objects into an array of my intended class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/395030/quick-java-question-casting-an-array-of-objects-into-an-array-of-my-intended-cl)

As others have said, you can't cast an Object[] to, well, anything. In this case, you have a Bag inside an Object array, so in this specific instance it seems like it might work. But imagine that you had a larger array, full of objects of different types. In that case, the cast wouldn't work. The program has to work for the general case.

You can solve this by:
1) Using a Bag[] type instead of Object[]
2) Using a List - collections are nearly always better
3) Using the Arrays class to create a new Bag[]: Arrays.copyOf(bagArray,bagArray.length,Bag[].class)