# How to get a array[] out of my LinkedList

Tags: java, list, collections

I need to convert my List:

```
List<Double> listFoo = new LinkedList<Double>();
```

to a array of double. So I tried:

```
double[] foo = listFoo.toArray();
```

But I get the error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object[] to double[]
```

How can I avoid this? I could Iterate over the list and create the array step by step, but I don't want to do it this way.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/960431/how-to-convert-listinteger-to-int-in-java

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/395030/quick-java-question-casting-an-array-of-objects-into-an-array-of-my-intended-cl

Answer (score 3):

You can't make the array of primitives with the standard List class's toArray() methods. The best you can do is to make a Double[] with the generic method [toArray( T[] )](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29).

```
Double[] foo = listFoo.toArray( new Double[ listFoo.size() ] );
```

One easy way to make a double[] is to use [Guava's Doubles class](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Doubles.html#toArray%28java.util.Collection%29).

```
double[] foo = Doubles.toArray( listFoo );
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to make, generic one

```
Double[] foo = listFoo.toArray(new Double[listFoo.size()]);
```

That would be the fastest way.

Using `new Double[listFoo.size()]` (with array size) you will reuse that object (generally it is used to make generic invocation of method `toArray`).

Answer (score 1):

It should work if you make `foo` an array of `Doubles` instead of `doubles` (one is a class, the other a primitive type).