# [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to error

Tags: java, hibernate

I get a list from my `query.list()`. After that, I want to display the object inside this list but I got this error for this line `for(Commerce[] c: this.newsList) {`

> java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Lcom.model.Commerce;
>       com.action.CommerceAction.searchCommerces(CommerceAction.java:35)

Here is my code:

My business service

```
public List<Commerce[]> getCommercesBySearch(String categorie, String lieux) {
    Query query = hibUtil.getSession().createQuery("from Commerce c, Categorie ca,Lieux l "
            + "where c.categorie=ca.idCategorie and c.lieux=l.idLieux and"
            + " ca.libelle='" + categorie + "' and l.ville='" + lieux + "' ");
    List<Commerce[]> tuples = (List<Commerce[]>) query.list();
    return tuples;
}
```

My action class

```
private CommerceService service;
private Commerce commerce = new Commerce();
private List<Commerce[]> newsList;
public String searchCommerces() {
    String libelle = ServletActionContext.getRequest().getParameter("libelle");
    String ville = ServletActionContext.getRequest().getParameter("ville");
    this.newsList = service.getCommercesBySearch(libelle,ville);
    for(Commerce[] c: this.newsList){
        System.out.println(c[0].getNom());
    }
    if (this.newsList.size() > 0) {
        return SUCCESS;
    }
    addActionError("Il n'existe aucun commerce de cette catégorie dans cette ville");   
    return ERROR;
    }
```

Comment: Do you actually try to get a list of Commerce[]? I think you want to get a List<Commerce> only. Maybe you should check the type of the variable ""tuples"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am certain that this statement:

```
List<Commerce[]> tuples = (List<Commerce[]>) query.list();
```

produces an unchecked type conversion warning. **Your code is [polluting the heap](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/155994/java-heap-pollution) by doing this unchecked type conversion.** `query.list()` returns a raw `List`, which will contain `Object[]`. Here is the [relevant Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/Query.html#list()):

> Return the query results as a `List`. If the query contains multiple results per row, the results are returned in an instance of `Object[]`.

[Note that you **cannot** cast an array to an array of it's sub-type.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/395030/quick-java-question-casting-an-array-of-objects-into-an-array-of-my-intended-cl)

There are a couple of ways to fix this problem:

1. Use `List<Object[]>` instead of `List<Commerce[]>`. You can then transform the result of the `list()` method into a more usable form, preferably within it's own method, before passing it on to the rest of your code. This is the preferable method if you need to select more than just the `Commerce` object.
2. Add `SELECT c` to the beginning of your query, this will allow you to do a safe `List<Commerce>` cast.

Comment: Great explanation of the problem. It will be great if you post how OP can solve this problem as well.

Comment: @durron597 Thought you had a template or so for formatting. But good explanation actually.

Comment: @MuratK. Thanks. I do have some practice at being the [Fastest Gun in the West](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem)

Comment: And... your solution is not the best =\

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza there really aren't any good ways to solve this problem. It's stupid that the latest version of Hibernate is returning a raw type, for any reason ever. How would you do it?

Comment: I would add `"SELECT c"` because OP wants/needs to obtain `Commerce` and there's this `"FROM Commerce c"` and do an (un)safe cast to `List<Commerce>` with no problems. And yes, Hibernate should offer method `List<T> Query#list<T>(Class<T>)` to make sure the data obtained is from an exact class.

Comment: thanks everybody for your help i added select c (the second solution) and that worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

Use `select c` before your `from` or you will have some trouble with the returned `Object[]`. If you don't use this, Hibernate will return a list of Object[] containing more than one object into this. For your problem it will be like:

- `Object[0]` is an instance of `Commerce`
- `Object[1]` is `Categorie`
- `Object[3]` is `Lieux`
- etc.

You will throw an `ClassCastException` if you try to cast `Object[]` into `Commerce`.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please elaborate further on what the trouble with your returned `Object` is, and I would be happy to upvote this answer.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advice. I just wanted to add comment but i have not enough reputation. Hope it is more comprehensive now.

Comment: I fixed your formatting some, and gave you an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem lies here:

```
 Query query = hibUtil.getSession().createQuery("from Commerce c, Categorie ca,Lieux l "
        + "where c.categorie=ca.idCategorie and c.lieux=l.idLieux and"
        + " ca.libelle='" + categorie + "' and l.ville='" + lieux + "' ");
List<Commerce[]> tuples = (List<Commerce[]>) query.list();
```

That's not correct, considering your idea. I believe that your query should return a `List<Commerce>`, not `List<Commerce[]>`.

```
List<Commerce> tuples = (List<Commerce>) query.list();
```

To make that works, you need to add **SELECT c** in your query:

```
SELECT c from Commerce c, Categorie ca,Lieux l...
```

It will select a list of object `Commerce`. If you leave the query like originally, it will return a list of Object array (actually they are Commerce[], Categorie[], Lieux[]...). Not to mention you can't cast directly an array in Java, the objects aren't the same type  anyway.

Comment: This answer is wrong. See my answer, which references the Hibernate documentation. It's not a `List<Commerce>`, it's a `List<Object[]>`

Comment: @durron597: it's quite strange to me then. Maybe I'm out of touch, but could you please explain what will be in the List<Object[]> ?

Comment: If there are multiple objects created in the row, the array will contain all of these objects. So one will be a `Commerce`, the next `Object` will be something else, etc.

Comment: Oh thanks for the info. I haven't read the question carefully I have updated my answer

Comment: This answer would be more useful to future visitors if you wrote it as if it had originally included the `SELECT c` bit, instead of saying "Edit: blah blah". StackOverflow is not a forum, it is a site for getting expert advice on questions; if people care about the history of an answer they can clicked on the edit link. If you fix it I will be happy to remove my downvote

Comment: [Further reading about using the word EDIT:](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127639/when-is-edit-update-appropriate-in-a-post)